# Command "echo" has no effect in awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a line of code that I need to run in a linux terminal and it`s not going very well.

What i`m doing is trying to output some variables obtained from my postfix mail queue to a file. For now I just need this piece of code working, but when I try to execute, nothing happens.

Code:

```
mailq | tail -n +2 | awk  'BEGIN { RS = "" } { echo $1  }' | tr -d '*!' >> myfile
```

Additional Notes:

If I change `echo` to `print` and remove `>> myfile` it works, but I need to output it to file.

Comment: `echo` is a builtin in your shell. But you're not executing `print` or `echo` in a shell, you're running it in `awk`. Try reading `man awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` doesn't have an `echo` command; it does have a `print` command. Making the replacement should be sufficient, without removing the `>> myfile`.

Tangentially, you can do away with the `tail` command by telling `awk` to ignore its first two lines of input and exiting immediately after the third.

```
mailq | awk  ' NR == 3 { print $1; exit  }' | tr -d '*!' >> myfile
```

Comment: I don't think `NR > 2` will work, because the script changes `RS`.

Comment: .. and also get rid of `tr` by doing `gsub(/[*!]/, "", $1)`

Comment: You only need to do the `gsub` on `$1`, since nothing else is being printed.